# Trouble with connection to the terminals of this filter

Tags: filter, wiring, wire-terminals

Below is a AC power line filter with open terminals as shown:

[image]

I couldn't find any practical information about the proper correct way to connect the AC wires to the terminals of this filter. Should the AC cables/wires be passed through those terminal holes and crimped in a way or soldered? Does anybody have experience with such terminals?

Comment: You could solder, or use Female Spade Crimp Terminals

Comment: If I find Female Spade Crimps, they should match these filter's terminals right? How can I know the gauge of these terminals so that I can buy female spades to fit in?

Comment: To find that data you would need to read the data sheet. For instance it will say something like this "Type /05 Industry-standard size fast-on terminal, 6.3 x 0.8mm
"

Comment: Link to the data sheet please.

Comment: @Andyaka Here is the datasheet: https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1523/0900766b81523ed9.pdf